# Visual Studio Code problem with C++ 20 Coroutine parts - suspend_never, suspend_always, co_await

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++-coroutine

I'm trying to switch from JetBrains CLion to VS Code. When I was trying some code that worked in CLion perfectly, I ran into troubles. I was trying to open only a basic coroutine implementation.

Line:

```
#include <coroutine>
```

is good, without errors, but when I try something like:

```
std::suspend_always initial_suspend()...
```

or:

```
co_await std::suspend_never() {}
```

VS Code shows problems that "*`namespace std contains no member suspend_always`*", etc.

Like I said- the only thing I did was that I opened the same code, that worked in CLion.

The first thing I tried was checking paths to compiler (mingw gcc) - the same as in CLion.

Then I tried to add the line

```
using namespace std;
```

, but it helped only on one line. I don't get it.

I tried also change `standard` in `cpp_properties.json` file to `"C++20"`.

Nothing on google helped me, but maybe I just don´t know what to search for.

Comment: You have to config VSCode properly. And they mean Properly! Select [the config guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/setup-overview) for your system, and follow the 15-page guide to the letter. If you miss one part, it just doesn't work. That's how it is. (And I don't like VSCode either - can you tell?).

Comment: @BoP I have the exact same feeling...it is just trash. Especially for C++...but I hope that I will manage to get there the bloody C++ support somehow.

Comment: I'm removing the ranty bits of your post. This is not a platform to rant (see [/help/dont-ask](/help/dont-ask)). Questions should strive to be objective and free of noise.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the .vscode/settings.json file paste this code:

```
{
    "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++20"
}
```